# Check if dragable's object and drop's zone tags are equal

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am making a puzzle game.

I randomly select an image from an array and split it in 4 parts.

My Layout consists of 3 TableRows.

The first row is a LinearLayout with 2 rows as well. This layout has the randomly selected image as a background with a transparency of 0.3

The second and third row are simply for the 4 parts of the split image.

So, i think my question and my description so far has made my problem clear already.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/puzzleBackground"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_weight=".5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:id="@+id/piece1"
                    android:tag="piece1"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:id="@+id/piece2"
                    android:tag="piece2"
                    />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_weight=".5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:id="@+id/piece3"
                    android:tag="piece3"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:id="@+id/piece4"
                    android:tag="piece4"
                    />

            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/part1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/part2" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/part3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/part4" />

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

```
public class Puzzle extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] puzzleIMGS;
private String randomPuzzleIMG;
private ImageView part1, part2, part3, part4;
private TextView piece1, piece2, piece3, piece4;
private LinearLayout puzzleBackground;
private Bitmap bm1, bm2, bm3, bm4;
private List<Bitmap> parts = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_puzzle);

    //Select random image
    puzzleIMGS = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.all_animal_imgs);
    randomPuzzleIMG = puzzleIMGS[new Random().nextInt(puzzleIMGS.length)];

    //Get the elements
    part1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.part1);
    part2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.part2);
    part3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.part3);
    part4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.part4);
    piece1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.piece1);
    piece2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.piece2);
    piece3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.piece3);
    piece4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.piece4);

    part1.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    part2.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    part3.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    part4.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    piece1.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    piece2.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    piece3.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    piece4.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

    //Convert randomly selected resource image to bitmap
    Bitmap originalBm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getImageId(this, randomPuzzleIMG));

    //Split bitmap to 4 parts
    bm1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBm, 0, 0, (originalBm.getWidth() / 2), (originalBm.getHeight() / 2));
    bm2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBm, (originalBm.getWidth() / 2), 0, (originalBm.getWidth() / 2), (originalBm.getHeight() / 2));
    bm3 = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBm, 0, (originalBm.getHeight() / 2), (originalBm.getWidth() / 2), (originalBm.getHeight() / 2));
    bm4 = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBm, (originalBm.getWidth() / 2), (originalBm.getHeight() / 2), (originalBm.getWidth() / 2), (originalBm.getHeight() / 2));

    //Make the background transparent
    piece1.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm1));
    piece1.setAlpha(0.3f);
    piece2.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm2));
    piece2.setAlpha(0.3f);
    piece3.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm3));
    piece3.setAlpha(0.3f);
    piece4.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm4));
    piece4.setAlpha(0.3f);

    //Place parts in an array
    parts.add(bm1);
    parts.add(bm2);
    parts.add(bm3);
    parts.add(bm4);

    //Shuffle the array
    Collections.shuffle(parts);

    //Assign the correct piece tag to each part
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(i==1) {
            part1.setImageBitmap(parts.get(i));
            if (parts.get(i).equals(bm1)){
                part1.setTag("piece1");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm2)){
                part1.setTag("piece2");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm3)){
                part1.setTag("piece3");
            } else {
                part1.setTag("piece4");
            }
        } else if(i==2){
            part2.setImageBitmap(parts.get(i));
            if (parts.get(i).equals(bm1)){
                part2.setTag("piece1");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm2)){
                part2.setTag("piece2");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm3)){
                part2.setTag("piece3");
            } else {
                part2.setTag("piece4");
            }
        } else if(i==3){
            part3.setImageBitmap(parts.get(i));
            if (parts.get(i).equals(bm1)){
                part3.setTag("piece1");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm2)){
                part3.setTag("piece2");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm3)){
                part3.setTag("piece3");
            } else {
                part3.setTag("piece4");
            }
        } else {
            part4.setImageBitmap(parts.get(i));
            if (parts.get(i).equals(bm1)){
                part4.setTag("piece1");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm2)){
                part4.setTag("piece2");
            } else if (parts.get(i).equals(bm3)){
                part4.setTag("piece3");
            } else {
                part4.setTag("piece4");
            }
        }
    }
}

private static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null, context.getPackageName());
}

private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

                if(view.getTag().equals("piece1")){
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    piece1.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm1));
                    piece1.setAlpha(0.9f);
                } else if (view.getTag().equals("piece2")){
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    piece2.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm2));
                    piece2.setAlpha(0.9f);
                } else if (view.getTag().equals("piece3")){
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    piece3.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm3));
                    piece3.setAlpha(0.9f);
                } else if (view.getTag().equals("piece4")){
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    piece4.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm4));
                    piece4.setAlpha(0.9f);
                }

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

}
So, my code they way it is right now, automatically places the dropped part on the correct place. For example, if i drag the first part from the screenshot i am showing above and drop it anywhere in the picture above, it will automatically go in the correct position and that's it. The same thing happens with all the parts.

[image]

What i want to do is, if i drop the part with the tag "piece1" above the textview with the tag "piece4" i want it to reject the drop and simply not place the part on the correct place automatically and not .removeView(view);

I am pretty sure this has to be implemented in the case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: and i think i have to modify my if statement from 
if(view.getTag().equals("piece1")){ 
to something like
if(view.getTag().equals(dropZone.getTag())){

Any help would be highly appreciated as i am pulling my hair over here.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i just solved it.

The only thing i had to do was simply nest my if statement of the DragEvent.ACTION_DROP inside another if statement like this

```
if(view.getTag().equals(v.getTag())){
    if(view.getTag().equals("piece1")){
        owner.removeView(view);
        piece1.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm1));
        piece1.setAlpha(0.9f);
    } else if (view.getTag().equals("piece2")){
        owner.removeView(view);
        piece2.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm2));
        piece2.setAlpha(0.9f);
    } else if (view.getTag().equals("piece3")){
        owner.removeView(view);
        piece3.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm3));
        piece3.setAlpha(0.9f);
    } else if (view.getTag().equals("piece4")) {
        owner.removeView(view);
        piece4.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm4));
        piece4.setAlpha(0.9f);
    }
}
```